# getting data from a db by passing a dynamic array

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch data from db where the tuples ids are match with the ids which I pass.

Example Id array: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, ...]`

The number of items can be vary according to different requests.

```
SELECT expense_type, expense_category FROM expense_type WHERE expense_category_id=id1 OR expense_category_id=id2;
```

`id1, id2` are the ids which comes from the frontend. (6,7,...)

There can be multiple ids which comes from the frontend. could I please know is there a way to fetch data from one query in such situation. Or else do I have to write multiple queries to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make query by using that multiple ids's array.

something like below.

or else you can iterate the same statement and push the results into an array and pass it to the frontend after the query finishes.

```
'SELECT expense_type, expense_category FROM expense_type WHERE expense_category_id IN (`;
forEach(ids as id) {
 query += id + ','
}
```